# hadoop word count and get the maximum occured word

Tags: hadoop, max, word-count

I am very new to hadoop. i have done with word-count and now I want to do a modification.

I want to get the word that has occurred most in a text file. If, normal word count program gives a output :

```
a 1
b 4
c 2
```

I want to write program that will give me output only

```
b 4
```

here my reducer function ::

```
public static class Reduce extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> 
{

 int max_sum=0;
 Text max_occured_key;

 public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context) 
  throws IOException, InterruptedException 
  {
    int sum = 0;
    for (IntWritable val : values) 
    {
        sum += val.get();           
    }
    if(sum > max_sum)
    {
        max_sum = sum;
        max_occured_key = key;

    }

    context.write(max_occured_key, new IntWritable(max_sum));
    //context.write(key, new IntWritable(sum));

  }
```

}

but it is not giving the right output.
Can anyone help plz ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're writing out the maximum value so far at the end of each reduce function - so you'll get more than a single entry per reducer. You're also running into reference re-use problems as you're copying the reference of the key to your max_occured_key variable (rather than copying the value).

You should probably amend as follows:

- Initialize the `max_occured_key` variable at construction time (to an empty Text)
- Call `max_occured_key.set(key);` rather than using the equals assignment - The reference the key parameter is reused for all iterations of the reduce method, so the actual object will remain the same, just the underlying contents will be amended per iteration
- Override the cleanup `method` and move the context.write call to that method - so that you'll only get one K,V output pair per reducer.

For example:

```
@Override
protected void cleanup(Context context) {
  context.write(max_occured_key, new IntWritable(max_sum));
}
```

The cleanup method is called once all the data has been passed through your map or reduce task (and is called per task instance (so if you gave 10 reducers, this method will be called for each instance).

Comment: thanks a lot. But I have a question :

Can you please exaplin your 3rd point... I did not get that.
and initialize max_occured_key at construction time means declare it as a public variable of the class WordCount ???

Comment: Can you give a example please ??

Comment: Added an example and a little more explaination. Let me know if you need anything explained in more detail

Comment: thanks man. 
How can I get the top 2 frequent words ? like for the given input, output should be :: b 4 & c 2 ... in general, how can I get the top N frequent word ?

Comment: For top N you need to maintain a 'priority set' in your reducers and either run a single reducer (not practical for larger datasets), or output the Top N for each reducer and run a second job with the first job as input to get the actual top n

Comment: Single reducer is an viable option here, but only when Combiner used too. In that case single reducer will get only N records, where N equals to number of Mappers.

Comment: @octo - but there's no guarantee that the combiner will run, or could run multiple times so the reducer may get more than N records per map task. You also have a problem that outputting the top N from any one mapper may/will not give you a wholistic answer when you get to the reduce phase as you only looking at Top N samples (i.e. one word could have a freq of 1 in each mapper, over 100 mappers that a freq of 100 in total, but be beaten by a word that have a freq of less than that globally, but more locally in any one mapper

Comment: @Cris, Ah, yes. TopN on map side can be done only in case of small amount of distinct keys which fit in memory. In other situations we need to use one reducer or two phases.